# If else statament

Tags: c#, if-statement

I need to return the credit card limit as string, I managed to create store procedure and the method in C# but now I don't know how to make the if else statements for the values that with be returned. Can anyone help me?

```
public static string sp_GetCCard_Limit(string docRoot)     
{
    DataTable a = cmdExecutor.ExecuteDataSet("sp_GetCCard_Limit", docRoot).Tables[0];
    return cmdExecutor.ExecuteDataSet("sp_GetCCard_Limit", docRoot).Tables[0].Rows[1]["VALUE"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: If you are using SP ,must directly implement conditional statement at SP only .!! Or you must explore your question more ..

Comment: when i debug my code the respond is that you don't have values in row 1.
what i am looking for is how to construct the if statement e.x
if(datatable is not null){ return blablabla}
else return 0

because every time i get an error :/

Comment: @OrgestLikaj please do not add these details as a comment, instead [edit] them into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
    public static string sp_GetCCard_Limit(string docRoot)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = cmdExecutor.ExecuteDataSet("sp_GetCCard_Limit", docRoot);
        if(dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
            if(dTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return dTable.Rows[0].["VALUE"].ToString();
            }
        }

        return ""; // default value for if no data found.
    }
```